# Trigger event on hover over the html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I have:

- An html table which can be dynamically enlarged by clicking two buttons: to add row and column.
- two one-row and one-column tables. One above and one to the left side of the table. These two tables are expanded simultaneously with the main table. When I add new row, left table ads new cell. When I add new column, top table ads new cell;
- two mentioned tables are hidden.

What I need:

- when I hover over a particular cell in main table, it(hovering) should trigger appearance of relevant cells in tables above and to the left. For example, if I hover over cell in row 2, column 2(of the main table) it should show cell 2 in top table and cell 2 in left table.
- So I need somehow to connect selected cell with the same cells in other tables and show them on hover.
- And I need to be able to move the pointer on the appeared cell to click it (it should not disappear when I move cursor from the main table to this cell)

The harder version of what I need supposes that hidden cells will not appear if only 1 row or column are left in the main table.

It will look like this:

[Picture of the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrVvp.png)

Since CSS allows to select on hover only elements that are inside one div or are siblings, I assume that this can be done only with JQuery.

I am using this code to show an entire hidden table on hover over the main table:

```
$('#my-table').hover(function() {  
  $('#dell-row').removeClass('hoverstate');
}, function() {
  $('#dell-row').addClass('hoverstate');
});
```

Now I think that I need to replace #my-table with the selector of the cell in #my-table table and #dell-row with the selector of the corresponding cell in #dell-row table. Any ideas how I can do this?

I can not indicate static coordinates of the cells because the table is dynamically changing.

Please take a look at the **working demo** with all the html, css and JS code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/gmzqe5kw/21/).

Comment: This question was partially answered by this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203962/on-mouseover-remove-class-of-the-nth-element-in-another-dom-object/50206432?noredirect=1#comment87435957_50206432