# On mouseover remove class of the nth element in another DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a blue table. When I hover the pointer over the particular cell in this table it should show (addClass/removeClass) particular cell in the top red table and particular cell in the left red table (they should stay hidden unless the blue table is hovered on).

Here is the pic. [image]

I have included `onmouseover="showDellCell()"` in each cell of the blue table (and after this Chrome refuses to show me my jsfiddle) and want to write a function that will understand which cell is hovered in a blue table and change class of two respective cells in two other tables. I can not indicate directly which cell should be shown because the table is dynamic and can be enlarged or shrunk. That is why it is important to find the connection between the blue cell and two respective cell ins red tables.

I guess it is possible to do this via `nth child`, but I wanted to do this via `closest`method. Here is the example code for the top table:

```
function showDellCell() {
  var columnDelIndex = $("td", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
  $($('del-column')[columnDelIndex]).removeClass("hide");

}
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can you please help me to make it work in any reasonable way? [Here is my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/bgfvn8aw/17/), but again, Chrome is blocking its performance, probably due to a lot of mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remove your function called `showDellCell()` on `onmouseover` event and change your event

```
<table class="my-table">
  <tr class="default-row">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

$('.my-table tr td').mouseover(function(){
    var columnDelIndex = $("td", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
   var col_num = $('.my-table tr:first > td').length;
   $($('.del-column-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex%col_num)]).removeClass('hide');
   $($('.del-row-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex/col_num)]).removeClass('hide'); 
})
```

[Check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/bgfvn8aw/22/)

Note : it just solves your question, but when you click add row or column, also event onmouseover raise :D

Updated : Issue in comment 
[How is it possible to hide irrelevant red cells again if I move the pointer to another blue cell (or hide them all if I move the pointer out of the blue table)](https://jsfiddle.net/bgfvn8aw/23/)

Comment: thank you, this is a very good solution, but there is a slight problem: if I add more rows/columns (with the yellow buttons), then this function does not work because static connection with integer 4 is used and so when there are more than 4 rows and columns - it does not work properly. Maybe it can be done in such way that it will work for any quantity of cells?

Comment: perfect, thank you! Maybe you could help me with another issue: do you know how is it possible to hide irrelevant red cells again if I move the pointer to another blue cell (or hide them all if I move the pointer out of the blue table)? Maybe I should use the same model as in your function but with mouseout and addClass(hide)?

Comment: Yes, `addClass` when `mouseout` , but if you `mouseover` red button it means `mouseout` the table. Maybe you need to `setTimout`

Comment: I use `mouseleave` instead. Suggestion for you in last edited

Comment: brilliant, thank you! The only tiny thing: it works flawlessly for the left red table but as for the top table, when I add new columns, it also adds red cells that do not disappear. And the bug looks different if I add just one column or more columns. Here are the pics: https://imgur.com/PS6IWkR and https://imgur.com/0QqIsOW Do you think it is solvable in any way or it can not be corrected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170591/discussion-between-mayua-and-ryuk-lee).